# Show Negative values on ASP.net Charts

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, series

I have created a chart and the area chart has negative values - how can i get these to show rather than just being cut off ? (is this possible). See image below for what i am looking for.

[image]

Comment: which library are you using for charts? can you show me your code to render the chart?

Comment: ASP.net chart controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `Minimum` (and `Maximum`) property for AxisY.

```
<AxisY  Minimum="-120" Maximum="100"> </AxisY>
```

refer [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.minimum.aspx) for documentation about `Axis.Minimum Property`

> Note that if you set this value explicitly, the X-values of data
>   elements must be taken into account. If all data points have X-values
>   of zero, the Chart control will assume the first data point occurs at
>   zero. Also, if the Minimum value is explicitly set, the
>   IsStartedFromZero property will be ignored. The Minimum value must be
>   less than the Maximum value. To automatically round the maximum and
>   minimum axis values call the RoundAxisValues method.

Another property to keep in consideration is `Axis.IsStartedFromZero Property`.
Refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.isstartedfromzero.aspx) for documentation.